# How can I transpose this dataframe in a way where the distinct values of a column become the column header?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe I would like to transpose in a specific way.
Here is a small part of the dataframe I'm working with.

```
    data = {
    'country_name': ['Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania'], 
    'year': [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2021, 2022, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], 
    'happiness_score' :[3.7235898971557617, 4.401778221130371, 4.758380889892578, 3.831719160079956, 3.782937526702881, 3.5721004009246826, 3.1308956146240234, 3.9828546047210693, 4.220168590545654, 2.6617181301116943, 2.694303274154663, 2.375091791152954, 2.4360344409942627, 1.2812711000442505, 4.634251594543457, 5.485469818115234, 5.268936634063721, 5.867421627044678, 5.510124206542969, 4.550647735595703, 4.81376314163208, 4.6066508293151855, 4.511100769042969, 4.639548301696777, 5.0044026374816895, 4.9953179359436035, 5.364909648895264, 5.255481719970703]
} 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE8ch.png)

How can I transpose the rows and columns in this dataframe so the resulting table looks like this?

```
distinct_years = df['year'].drop_duplicates().sort_values().reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
distinct_countries = df['country_name'].drop_duplicates().sort_values().reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)['country_name'].tolist()

df_2 = distinct_years
df_2[distinct_countries] = np.nan
df_2
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3wHI.png)

But only with the happiness_score inserted into the rows corresponding to year and country.

Comment: Welcome back. Could you please edit your question so as to share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).  To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that I need to use pivot() not transpose.

pd.pivot(df, index='year', columns='country_name', values='happiness_score')

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANYq2.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mre]. SO guidelines are to avoid pictures whenever possible.